# Best way to Share Data Between Stored Procedure and trigger

Tags: sql-server

suppose i am calling a Stored Procedure and sending some params. the Stored Procedure will update a table and a trigger is there for that table. so when Stored Procedure update table then i want which user is updating the table but i am not using sql server user name rather i will send user names to SP who will update the table. so before update i can store that user name in local temp table and query that local temp table from trigger to get that user name. i hope it is possible but i want to other good option to achieve this job. so please share idea. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the user name in the procedure into the session using [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx)
This can be read in the trigger by [CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)

This is concurrency safe: each session/call is isolated from any other.
And no need for a temp table or such.

```
DECLARE @context varbinary(100) = CAST('foobar' AS varbinary(100));

SET CONTEXT_INFO @context;

SELECT CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS varchar(100));
```

Comment: thanks. i do not know much about CONTEXT_INFO. so please it seems one CONTEXT_INFO is available for each session.can we store two different data in two different CONTEXT_INFO in my SP and later read back those two different data from two CONTEXT_INFO from trigger. is it possible.can i give any name for each CONTEXT_INFO?

Comment: @Thomas: no, you only have one value. It is varbinary(128). You could encode 2 bits of info if you wanted into this...